# Cut last value of a string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

My data is like (a.txt)

```
allheartweb.com
whoisdatacenter.com
domainsanalytics.com
covercian.co.uk
```

I want to extract all TLD from there

My code is

```
cut -d "." -f 2 a.txt
```

its show me

```
com
com
com
co
```

if I do

```
cut -d "." -f 2,3
```

it gave me

```
com
com
com
co.uk
```

I want

```
com
com
com
uk
```

Any idea how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk -F'.' '{ print $NF }' infile
```

The `$` in awk is an operator that returns the content of the corresponding valid field.

fields in awk are splitting based on the FS (Field Seperator), which default is Tab(s)/Space(s) (Note: with default FS, all the leading/trailing whitespaces will be ignored too and if you wanted to capture them and so capture thr empty first/last fields then you will need to specify the FS as a regex type.). the FS can be changed with `-F` switch or via awk internal FS variable.

The `NF` in awk represent the last field, so by `$NF` we are telling to print last field's content based on the *dot* `.` as the FS.